# Problems creating Yosemite USB bootable drive

Tags: macos, usb, startup

I was trying to make a USB boot loader for Yosemite using this command

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled 2 --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

I borrowed it from the original

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

Which has worked for tons of people. The issue is for some reason it doesn't recognize the name of my volume is Untitled 2. 
Error message:

```
/Volumes/Untitled is not a valid volume mount point.
```

I don't understand why it isn't reading the 2. Is there another way to point the command to the partition without using the names given e.g. serial addressing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled 2 --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

to

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume "/Volumes/Untitled 2" --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

or

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled\ 2 --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

and it should work.

You have to escape spaces in paths in the command line either with a `\` or quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this path instead:

```
/Volumes/Untitled\ 2/
```

The backslash tells the terminal that the space is included in the path, otherwise it thinks your volume is called /Volumes/Untitled and that there is a random 2 argument in the command.

Comment: I liked your answer, it is simple yet it explains clearly. (+1)

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. honestly I knew that I just didn't have my head in the right place I was so frustrated. Thanks for that. I had to mark the other answer as correct because I just copied his code haha

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently when trying to re-install Sierra on an older machine. None of the helpful tips from a few years ago seemed to work. Apple's installer certificates expired in Oct of 2019 and the installers all had to be replaced. However, Apple included a bug with the Sierra installer and I was stuck! I reached out to a friend and he came up with a clever way to solve it. I can verify that with his instructions, I was able to create a Sierra installer on a USB drive using an image I downloaded from Apple after Oct 24, 2019. This image was able to boot a MacBook Air and that I was able to re-install the Sierra OS with that USB drive. If anyone else has this issue in 2020, follow these instructions:

https://krieger.io/creating-bootable-macos-sierra-installation-media-on-macos-catalina/

Answer (score -2):

sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction